# Select 100+ millions of rows in HSQLDB

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, hsqldb

I have to iterate through a table with 100+ millions of records with JDBC on a HSQLDB database and I don't manage to do it in a reasonable time. I use hsqldb v2.4.0.

I tried to use a `PreparedStatement` with the following query to slice the data:

```
String select = "SELECT ID, NAME, VALUE FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY ID OFFSET ? ROWS FETCH ? ROWS ONLY";
```

The problem is that it takes more and more time as we go through the table. Note that the `ID` column is indexed.

I tried to put a fetch size but it doesn't work either :

```
String select = "SELECT ID, NAME, VALUE FROM MY_TABLE";
PreparedStatement selectStatement = connection.prepareStatement(select, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
selectStatement.setFetchSize(5000);
```

And then I iterate through the `ResultSet` :

```
ResultSet result = selectStatement.executeQuery();
while (result.next()) {
    Long id = result.getLong(1);
    // do stuff ...
}
```

HSQLDB still tries to fetch all the rows of the table and the returned `ResultSet`doesn't fit in memory. Here is the stacktrace :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.hsqldb.navigator.RowSetNavigatorData.ensureCapacity(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.navigator.RowSetNavigatorData.add(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.buildResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.getResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementQuery.getResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at com.jolbox.bonecp.PreparedStatementHandle.executeQuery(PreparedStatementHandle.java:174)
at myclass at the line ResultSet result = selectStatement.executeQuery();
```

Is there a way to achieve this in HSQLDB?

Comment: How do you loop through the `ResultSet`?

Comment: I use a regular while loop : `while (result.next()) ...`

Comment: What is your HSQLDB version?

Comment: I would like to know the content of your loop. How do you do with each record.

Comment: I use hsqldb v2.4.0 (last version).

Comment: I am wondering if you have put all the returned records in memory. Is that your program halts in the middle of the loop or somewhere else?

Comment: Try to add connection.setAutoCommit(false); before creating prepared statement.

Comment: @Alex The `selectStatement.executeQuery()`doesn't even complete.

Comment: @egorlitvinenko ok I'll try that

Comment: `ResultSets` don't have to fit into memory. They only have to contain one row at a time. It is *your code* that doesn't fit into memory. Solution: fix it. You would be infinitely better off *not* trying to select hundreds of millions of rows and then process them in code, but rather to select only the rows you really need, via some appropriate `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I actually have to select all the rows of the table.

Comment: @Patrick Difficult to believe. Why?

Comment: @EJP I have to migrate all the data of this table to different tables.

Comment: So don't try to load the entire table into memory. `ResultSet` doesn't do that: that's why it has a `next()` method. The problem is in your own code, and the stack trace will prove it.

Comment: That's why I don't want to load all the `ResultSet` in memory, by putting a fetch size to the statement, and it doesn't work. That's the point of my question.

Comment: So post the stack trace and we'll see who is throwing the exception.

Comment: why do you need to load the data from server to client and then back to other tables? is it possible that you create a routine that performs the migration to other tables?

Comment: @Patrick, if you are migrating data to another table, you may also try to use purely SQL to do that. Something like `insert into NEWTABLE select ID, NAME, VALUE from MY_TABLE` should be worked for you. It should be the most efficient way and does not require the data to transfer between server and client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is not related to memory use, as not too much memory is used for this type of SELECT.

The increase in time to select the result is expected. The OFFSET clause in the SELECT indicates how many rows are skipped. As it gets larger, more rows are selected and skipped.

You need to modify your SELECT to:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, VALUE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID > ? ORDER BY ID FETCH ? ROWS ONLY
```

And you process the result like this, using a running lastID with a PreparedStatement.

```
long lastID = -1;

// repeat the rest of the code until the result is empty
selectStatement.setLong(1, lastID);
selectStatement.setInt(2, 100000);

ResultSet result = selectStatement.executeQuery();
while (result.next()) {
 Long id = result.getLong(1);
 lastID = id;
 // do stuff ...
}
```

And

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the program is running and it's going fast (10 millions rows processed in 4 minutes).